# Loop through $_FILES causes JSON unexpected Token

Tags: php, json

***** Update:** The issue I believe is with the dSubmit function, it might not be handling multipart form data therefore causes PHP to throw an error when the foreach is executed? I've submitted over arrays through the function without issue, is there something different with the files[]

I have a AJAX form submission on a website, the JSON array that is returned is used to show message or direct to another page.  Everything works well until I loop through file uploads sent through the form via the PHP script.  I have removed all possible extra code so it is now bare bones and I still can't resolve it:

upload.php

```
<?php

foreach($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name){};

$returnData = array(
    
        "infoMsg"       => "message for user",
        "color"         => "orange"
    );  
echo json_encode($returnData);
?>
```

html snippet:

```
<form id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="file" id="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple"/>
        
    </form>

    <button onclick="dSubmit('fileUpload' , 'inc/upload.php')">test</button>
```

dSubmit is the function to submit the form, everything is working as expected until I introduce the looping of the uploaded files.  The error I receive is:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

I can see no extra characters/whitespace or anything else that might cause the JSON issue.

Here's the dSubmit code found in the head:

```
function dSubmit(formName, formAction){
    // formName         = id of Form to process
    // formAction       = php file to parse data to
    var url = formAction;
    event.preventDefault()

    for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances )
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();

        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: url,
               data: $("#" + formName).serialize(), 
               success: function(returnData)
               {
                    var data = JSON.parse(returnData);  // Return php array from formAction
                    var passedInfoMsg   = (data['infoMsg']);    // infoMsg (if set)
                    var color           = (data['color']);      // infoMsg color (if set)
                    var resetForm       = (data['reset']);      // boolean reset submitted form upon submission
                    var fileToLoad      = (data['fileToLoad']); // fileToLoad (if set)
                    var divToLoad       = (data['divToLoad']);  // divToLoad fileToLoad in (if set)
                    console.log("Form Return: passedInfoMsg: " + passedInfoMsg + " | color: " + color + " | Reset: " + resetForm + " | fileToLoad: " + fileToLoad + " | divToLoad: " + divToLoad);
                        
                    if(passedInfoMsg!==undefined) {
                        // If message defined, display message
                        infoMsg(passedInfoMsg,color);
                    }
                    if(resetForm===true) {
                        // clear submitted form upon request from formAction
                        clearForm($("#"+formName))
                    }
                        
                    if(fileToLoad!==undefined) {
                        // if fileToLoad is set, run dLoader
                        dLoader(fileToLoad,divToLoad);
                    }
               }
            });

            return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
        }
```

The full code as requested:

storage.php ( where uploads take place ):

```
<?php

    require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../vendor/bucketScripts/start.php';  // include AWS email parser

    $folderTitle = "Client Portal";
    $projectId  = "36";
    $folder     = "client";

$objects = $s3->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
    "Bucket" => "openplanman",
    "Prefix" => "Projects/$projectId/$folder/" //must have the trailing forward slash "/"
));
$passedPrefix = "Projects/$projectId/$folder/";
?>


        <div class="row">
        <div class="12u 12u$(medium)">
        <h3><?php echo $folderTitle;?></h3>
        </div>
    
    <form id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="inc/uploadFiles.php" target="_blank">
    
        <input type="hidden" name="projectId" value="<?php echo $projectId;?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="uploadFolder" value="<?php echo $folder;?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="folderTitle" value="<?php echo $folderTitle;?>">
        
        <input type="file" id="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>

    <button onclick="dSubmit('fileUpload' , 'inc/uploadFiles.php')">test</button>
    
    
    <div class="12u 12u$(medium)">
    <table>
<?php
$fileArray  = array();
foreach ($objects as $object) {
// Load into a new array    
    array_push($fileArray, $object['Key']); 
}

foreach ($fileArray as $file) {

    $noPrefixFileName = str_replace("$passedPrefix","",$file);
    if($noPrefixFileName!=null)
    {
        $urlFilename = urlencode($noPrefixFileName);
        
    echo "<tr><td>" . $noPrefixFileName . "</td><td><a onclick=\"fileRequest.php?id=$projectId&folder=$folder&req=$urlFilename\" target='_blank'><i class='fa fa-cloud-download' aria-hidden='true'></a></td><td><i class='fa fa-eye' aria-hidden='true'></td></tr>";
    }
    
}   
?>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

uploadFiles.php (PHP script that handles the upload, works when POST not through AJAX)

```
<?php


require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../vendor/bucketScripts/start.php';  

$err = 0;


$projectId = $_POST['projectId'];

$uploadFolder       = $_POST['uploadFolder'];


$path =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../tmp/';  // include AWS email parser
$bucketPath = "../../../tmp/";


if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    // Loop $_FILES to exeicute all files
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {     
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
            continue; // Skip file if any error found
        }          
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {              
         // No error found! Move uploaded files 
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name))
                
        $fileName = $_FILES["files"]["name"][$f];
        
        
        
        //  echo "<br>Key: " . "Projects/$projectId/$uploadFolder/$fileName";
        //  echo "<br>Source: " . "$bucketPath$fileName";
        
                try {
            $s3->putObject([
                'Bucket'     => $config['s3']['bucket'],
                'Key'        => "Projects/$projectId/$uploadFolder/$fileName",
                'SourceFile' => "$bucketPath$fileName", 
                'ACL'        => 'public-read',
    ]);
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    
$err = 1;

    
    
            }
            
unlink($path.$name); // Housekeeping
        }
    }
    
}

            $returnData = array(
    
        "infoMsg"       => "user message",
        "color"         => "orange",

    );  
        


    echo json_encode($returnData);
?>
```

Comment: there's a `<` in your response. look there.

Comment: We cannot debug what we cannot see, and what we see while it looks a little odd ( overly summarised) should not be causing this error

Comment: Which part issues that warning? PHP or your browser? And are you sure that adding a single line containing a useless `foreach` loop causes that error?

Comment: @RiggsFolly would it help with I added the JS behind dSubmit?  I just didn't want to bloat the question out

Comment: Probably, but currently we have next to ZERO info to go on. We are not even sure from your question where that error messaging is being generated from

Comment: @NicoHaase The useless loop did upload the files to a S3 bucket but I removed it trying to get to the bottom of the issue.  The issue comes from the browser, running it as a standard POST submit to a new page results in the expected JSON being return.

Comment: So, you've cut out code that causes the problem and left the one that runs fine?

Comment: Does the `foreach` also builds the `$returnData` with more data than you currently show?

Comment: @RiggsFolly the foreach was for file uploading the result of which is passed to $returnData

Comment: So something in the foreach could be messing up yor array, so lets see that code

Comment: @RiggsFolly The code so far updated the question

Comment: @RiggsFolly I believe the issue points at dSubmit, I don't think it has the right set up for multipart froms

Answer (score 0):

Hope It's helpful..!
Your files array becomes like:-

```
$_FILES['files'][0]['name']
$_FILES['files'][1]['name']
```

When you do multiple file upload.

Comment: I dont think that is specifically the OP's issue. _And this is basically just a comment, as it is definitely not an answer_ Please dont comment is Answers. You only need 31 more reps and you can comment on any question, but downvotes will just make that take longer

Answer (score 0):

you got this error because there is a PHP error response that treated by the browser as json content and it's not.

you can find out that error response through the chrome developer tools

- press F12 to open the developer tools
- select Network tab
- select XHR filter
- select the request that you make
- on the right side you can find the response tab which will content the raw response

by the way i think your problem is your code try to iterate through $_FILES['files']['name'] which is string :)

Comment: Now that's more helpful... Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/parent/inc/uploadFiles.php on line 20
{"infoMsg":"user message","color":"orange"}

Comment: Would data: `code` $("#" + formName).serialize() `code` within the dSubmit work for multi part forms??

Comment: write ** var_dump($_FILES['files']['name']); exit(); ** before foreach and watch the result in the developer tools and compare it to what you are trying to do in the foreach

Comment: or use **var_dump($_FILES); exit();** to see what does php receive from the browser